# How do I create a status dialog box in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a database report generator in Excel. I am trying to create a dialog box that displays status information as the program runs.

When I generate the report, although the dialog box appears, I cannot refresh/update the information it displays. Most of the time, the dialog box only partially appears. I have tried using the .repaint method, but I still get the same results. I only see the complete dialog box, after the report is generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below works well when performing actions within Excel (XP or later).

For actions that take place outside Excel, for example connecting to a database and retrieving data the best this offers is the opportunity to show dialogs before and after the action (e.g. *"Getting data"*, *"Got data"*)

Create a form called **"frmStatus"**, put a label on the form called **"Label1"**.

Set the form property **'ShowModal' = false**, this allows the code to run while the form is displayed.

```
Sub ShowForm_DoSomething()

    Load frmStatus
    frmStatus.Label1.Caption = "Starting"
    frmStatus.Show
    frmStatus.Repaint
'Load the form and set text

    frmStatus.Label1.Caption = "Doing something"
    frmStatus.Repaint

'code here to perform an action

    frmStatus.Label1.Caption = "Doing something else"
    frmStatus.Repaint

'code here to perform an action

    frmStatus.Label1.Caption = "Finished"
    frmStatus.Repaint
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    frmStatus.Hide
    Unload frmStatus
'hide and unload the form

End Sub
```

Comment: This even works when Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Answer (score 7):

I have used Excel's own status bar (in bottom left of window) to display progress information for a similar application I developed in the past.

It works out very well if you just want to display textual updates on progress, and avoids the need for an updating dialog at all.

Ok @JonnyGold, here's an example of the kind of thing I used...

```
Sub StatusBarExample()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    ' turns off screen updating
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True 
    ' makes sure that the statusbar is visible
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while performing task 1..."
    ' add some code for task 1 that replaces the next sentence
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while performing task 2..."
    ' add some code for task 2 that replaces the next sentence
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    Application.StatusBar = False 
    ' gives control of the statusbar back to the programme
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know it's an old post, but terrific solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Echo Alan. Old post, still a great idea!

Answer (score 6):

Try adding a **DoEvents** call in your loop.  That should allow the form to repaint & accept other requests.

Answer (score 2):

Insert a blank sheet in your workbook
Rename the Sheet  eg. "information"

```
Sheets("information").Select
Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Updating Records"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
```

*Continue Macro*

```
Sheets("information").Select
Range("C3").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Preparing Information"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
```

*Continue Macro*

Etc
Alternatively select a blank cell somewhere on the existing sheet instead of inserting a new sheet

```
Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Updating Records"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
```

Etc

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box is also running on the same UI thread. So, it is too busy to repaint itself. Not sure if VBA has good multi-threading capabilities.